# transfer music files to Nexus 4 from computer with Windows 7

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-4, music

I have a Nexus 4, and have tried - and failed - to transfer some music downloads (FLAC 16bit) from my Windows 7 computer.

When I connect the phone, I can transfer the files and the computer tells me it succeeds, but I can't find any music on my phone. The alleged folder the music should go to is called `Internal Storage/Music`. Where is this folder on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

With my Nexus 4, that directory - which shows up as `Internal Storage` in Windows - can be located at a few different places depending on configuration. The places that I know of include...

- `/mnt/shell/0/`
- `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/`
- `/mnt/sdcard/`

  Most of the time, there's a link to this folder (So you don't need to find it) at: (*If this works, don't worry about the above directory paths too much*)
- `/sdcard/`

  This means that you should probably be able to find your music at `/sdcard/Music/`.

**Another note**: I don't know if the default music player supports FLAC audio. If it doesn't, then that would explain why it isn't locating the music automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the files are there, but you don't have a music app that will support .flac files, so they don't show up as visible.

I use one of 2 apps: Airdroid, or ES File explorer to transfer files wirelessly.  Both of these apps seem to assist in ensuring the files get to the proper place on the OS filesystem.